# Perl помогите разобраться с HTML::Parser

Tags: парсер, perl

Гуглил, читал, примеры смотрел, но принцип работы парсера не понимаю...

```
sub title_handler {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->handler(text => sub { print @_ }, "dtext");
    $self->handler(end  => "eof",            "self");
}

my $p = HTML::Parser->new(
    api_version => 3,
    start_h     => [\&title_handler, "self"],
    report_tags => ['title'],
);
```

К примеру этот код выводит тайтл, но как его переработать чтобы он дополнительно показывал все теги h2?

Comment: а какую задачу вы вообще решаете?

Comment: показать одноременно текст в title и h2 тегах

Comment: я не знаком с HTML::Parser, так что мне мало кода, чтобы сделать минимальный воспроизводимый пример. что подаётся на вход? как дальше обрабатывается?

Comment: html код, да хоть этой же страницы

Answer (score 1):

В принципе, не сложно. Только, надо понимать, что такое callback-функция.
В данном примере callback-функции регистрируются дважды:

```
 $self->handler(text => sub { print @_ }, "dtext");
...
 start_h     => [\&title_handler, "self"],
```

Вообще надо выяснить, какие параметры принимают эти функции. Тогда будет ясно, в какую из них добавить логику для имени тега `tytle` или `h2`.

Похоже, что в самом простом виде достаточно дополнить список тегов вторым тегом, и существующий обработчик (callback-функция `sub { print @_ }`) будет тупо печатать текст из обоих тегов:

т.е. попробовать в массив

```
report_tags => ['title'],
```

добавить второй тег

```
report_tags => [qw(title h2)],
```